# Affine connection on a Lie group - interaction with left-multiplication

Tags: lie-groups, connections

Let $X, Y$ be left invariant vector fields on a Lie group $G$, equipped with come arbitrary connection $\nabla$. Also, let $L_g : G \to G$ be left-multiplication by $g \in G$, so that for example $X \circ L_g (.) = X_{L_g(.)} : G \to TG$. I would assume that the following identity holds;
$$\nabla_{(X \circ L_g)} (Y\circ L_g) = \nabla_X Y \circ L_g\hspace{2mm}.$$

It seems really simple to prove, but I'm stuck. Could someone give a hint?

I know that the value of $\nabla_X Y |_p$ is determined by the value of $X$ only at *p* and on *Y* on a neighbourhood of *p*. However I can't figure out how to handle the "$\circ L_g$" in $\nabla_X Y \circ L_g$.

**Edit**: the vector fields *X* and *Y* are assumed to be left-invariant.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to prove the impossible.

**Counterexample**: let $G=\mathbb{R}$, with global coordinate $t$.  What you are asserting is that every connection has to be
$$
\nabla_{\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}}\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}=c\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}
$$
where $c$ is constant.  But this is not true, e.g., $\nabla_{\mathrm{d}/\mathrm{d}t}\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}=\sin(t)\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}$ is a connection (and descends to a connection on $S^1$ if you want a compact example).

Comment: Thank you, but I don't quite understand why, in your example, "my" formula implies that every connection should be of the form $c \frac{d}{dt}$ - could you elaborate a bit? Furthermore, I realize that I don't even understand if what I wrote is well-defined. For excample, I don't know if $\nabla_{(X \circ L_g)}(Y \circ L_g)$ is a well-defined vector field, since $h \mapsto \nabla_{(X \circ L_g)}(Y \circ L_g) |_h$ is not in $T_h G$, but in $T_{gh} G$... I wrote a new related question, where I include full context and motivation.

Comment: Link to my related question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3289811/understanding-the-definition-of-a-left-invariant-connection-on-a-lie-group

Comment: @user10354138 Could you help me with this please https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3292324/show-the-quotient-space-of-a-finite-collection-of-disjoint-2-simplices-obtained? Thank you!